# Getting NullPointerException on using List of mocked Object in a for loop

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The function to be mocked is of class `NegotiateNode`:

```
protected String getAttributeValueFromNodeOfServiceType(String serviceType, String attributeName) {
    String attributeValue = null;

    for (Node node : this.getListOfNodes()) {
        if (node.getServiceType().equals(serviceType)) {
            attributeValue = node.getAttribute(attributeName);
            break;
        }
    }

    return attributeValue;
}
```

And this is the test:

```
@Mock private NegotiateNode mockN;
@Mock private Node mockNode;
private List<Node> mockListOfNodes = Arrays.asList(mockNode, mockNode, mockNode);

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception
{
     when(mockN.getListofNodes()).thenReturn(mockListofNodes);  
}

@Test
public void getAttributeValueFromNodeOfServiceType_ServiceTypeExists_ReturnAttribute() {

     when(mockNode.getServiceType()).thenReturn("PMN", "AMC", "SMC");
     when(mockNode.getAttribute(anyString()).thenReturn("mockedValue");

     when(NegotiateNode.getAttributeValueFromNodeOfServiceType(anyString(), anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();

     assertEquals("mockedValue", mockN.getAttributeValueFromNodeOfServiceType("AMC", "dummyAttribute"));

}
```

I'm getting `NullPointerException` on running this test. The cause is that inside the for loop value of node is `null`. This seems to be because of the way `List` works in java. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add mockNodes to the list inside the setup method.

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception
{
    mockListOfNodes = Arrays.asList(mockNode, mockNode, mockNode);
    when(mockN.getListofNodes()).thenReturn(mockListofNodes);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, normis. That worked. Could you also explain the reason behind this?

Comment: No, currently the List is populated when it is declared. Mockito needs to call MockitoAnnotations.initMocks internally (inside the MockitoJUnitRunner class) before mocks are available and initialised.